# How to configure Postman to send logs to Azure Elastic Cloud?

Tags: azure, postman, elastic-stack

As part of sending data from Postman to Azure Elastic Cloud for testing purposes, I have configured the Elastic Cloud instance and tried the Elastic Search URL, API_KEY in Postman. But always I am getting an Authentication error. Can anyone please guide me in configuring the Postman to ingest the data into Elastic search and see the logs in Kibana?

Thanks in advance,
RK.